# How do I get unique values of a column in AWS Dynamo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Say, in AWS Dynamo, I have a table like this:

```
ID (HKey)   Date (RKey)   BoxName
0           1/1/2014      Box-1
1           2/1/2014      Box-1
2           3/1/2014      Box-2
3           4/1/2014      Box-3
4           5/1/2014      Box-3
5           5/1/2014      Box-1
```

I want to, in a single query, get the first row for each unique Box. There could be hundreds of boxes I need the first entry for at once, making individual requests inefficient.

I can't seem to find anything in the API that would allow me to do this. Is it possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider creating a Global secondary index (GSI) on Boxname (hash key) and date as your range key. This will enable you to use Query API on the secondary index where you can query "Find all IDs with Boxname = $box".

See the [documentation for GSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

Hope this helps,
Swami

Comment: Not quite what I'm after. I've edited the question to reflect that I want the first of each box in one query.

Comment: GSI is what you want. As mentioned in the answer above, you can do a "query" on the GSI with box name as hash key. Since GSI would sort box of same name with Date, you can set the limit of your query to 1 to get the oldest box. The only thing is you might want to create a separate table which contains all the box names.

Comment: I have a similar request and I do not believe your answering the question. The problem is how to obtain the list of unique boxnames? Using a GSI with boxname as hashkey you can only query if you know the boxname. This person wants to find all box names when they do not know them.

Comment: @BruceMacKenzie Actually, if you create a GSI, you will already have the primary key as box name, so you will have the unique ones

Comment: @Timotei Any advice on how exactly to do that? I have the GSI already created, but I need to find the unique values.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to query just for the first appearance of each box without creating an index for the boxes as suggested above. However, if you don't mind reading the whole table and then picking the right lines, then read the whole table into an array, and then make it unique by some simple piece of code. For example, suppose you've read the table into an array (note that you might have to make several calls to scan or query until you get them all), and the array is something like this:

```
l = [
    {"ID": "0", "Date": "1/1/2014", "BoxName": "Box-1"},
    {"ID": "1", "Date": "2/1/2014", "BoxName": "Box-1"},
    {"ID": "2", "Date": "3/1/2014", "BoxName": "Box-2"},
    {"ID": "3", "Date": "4/1/2014", "BoxName": "Box-3"},
    {"ID": "4", "Date": "5/1/2014", "BoxName": "Box-3"},
    {"ID": "5", "Date": "5/1/2014", "BoxName": "Box-1"}
]
```

Then, a simple code like this in python will give you the list in the variable "out":

```
    out = []
    seen = []
    for line in l:
        if line["BoxName"] not in seen:
            seen.append(line["BoxName"])
            out.append(line)
```